# UWP subscribe keyboard input event / get hidden keyboard input

Tags: input, bluetooth, keyboard, win-universal-app

with my smartphone I connect a bluetooth HID Device wich sends data as keyboard input (it's a RFID Reader). Now I wrote an UWP app to consume this input. But the problem is, that I cannot get the keyboard input events without the focus on a control like a textbox.

In my app I have a rootFrame with a splitView (Menu and Content) and in the Content-View I have a new frame where I load the pages.

I tried out the KeyDown-Event of the Pages, but it doesn't work correctly, because the focus is not always at the page (if the user touch on the nav-panel, the focus is switched to the mainFrame).

So, is it possible to add an eventHandler to the keyboard-input? or are there other practices to solve this problem?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for a better way, and this is not a complete answer, as I still have to click somewhere inside the page before the keyboard will take focus, but it's a start:

```
<Grid x:Name="PageGrid"
      KeyDown="{x:Bind ViewModel.OnKeyboardNumberInput, Mode=OneWay}"
```

and then in my ViewMode's PageLoaded event:

```
    public void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var grid = sender as Grid;

        // Find the OutputValueTextBlock and set keyboard focus to it.
        var tb = (TextBlock)grid.FindName("OutputValueTextBlock");
        tb.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

Comment: nice idea, but it laks at the point the user use the navigation. So the focus is lost from the pageGrid and the KeyDown-Event is not fired anymore. I still tried your example.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += KeyPress;
```

It worked for me.